# System.currentTimeMillis measuring time

Tags: java

When I use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure the time, is it safe?

E.g. When a time-shift happens (summer->winter time) will this produce an error?

Comment: You meant during day time saving ? AFAIK, it won't affect.

Comment: Read [the documentation!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of elapsed milliseconds since the Unix epoch (midnight at the start of January 1st 1970, UTC). This does *not* depend on your local time zone at all.

In other words, if you call it once per second, it will *always* increase by about 1000 (the "about" is only due to clock accuracy and the impossibility of the calls being *exactly* 1 second apart). It doesn't matter if your local time zone changes its offset from UTC, or if you even change your whole time zone - that will be irrelevant.

In theory, leap seconds make all of this trickier - but in practice most applications can get away with notionally sticking their fingers in their ears and saying "I'm not at home to Mr Leap Second."

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will return the milliseconds since [epoch (1/1/1970 00:00:00)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). How those are interpreted is a completely different story (and summer/winter time as well as timezone belong to the interpretation part). So yes, it would be save.